2D diagonal movement in Unity
I'm very new to Unity and am trying to set up 8 directional movement and animation for my Sprite. At present, 4 directional movement (up, down, left, right) is working fine, but diagonal movement is not working for all but one direction. This is what happens:
Press Right + Down: Right walking animation (correct)
Press Right + Up: Up walking animation (incorrect, I want Right Walking animation)
Press Left + Down: Down walking animation (incorrect, I want Left Walking animation)
Press Left + Up: Up walking animation (incorrect, I want Left Walking animation)
In summary, if travelling horizontally I want to favour the horizontal/x axis animation.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Animator animator;

    
    //get input from player
    //apply movement to sprite 

    private void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, vertical);

        AnimateMovement(direction);

        transform.position += direction * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    void AnimateMovement(Vector3 direction)
    {
        if (animator != null)
        {
            if(direction.magnitude > 0)
            {
                animator.SetBool("isMoving", true);
                animator.SetFloat("horizontal", direction.x);
                animator.SetFloat("vertical", direction.y);
            }
            else
            {
                animator.SetBool("isMoving", false);
            }
        }
    }

}


what makes you think its the code here thats the issue and not your animation tree?

you could try and check if direction.maginude is > 1. thats the case if you move diagonaly. if thats the case set "horizontal" to dirextion.x and "vertical" to 0. this only fixes the "symptom" but not the the cause, so i would sugest looking further into your animation tree.

As friends pointed out, the problem is definitely in your animation tree.

As several of you helpfully suggested....the problem was indeed in my animation tree! Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction!
